Branching strategy with two teams with different release cycles
what I have
We have two teams with different release cycles. The teams work in the same solution, but don't change the same files.
We have a developer team that uses 2 week sprints and delivers after each sprint. After the sprint is done, they will create a release branch and release to the Test, Acceptance and eventually Production environment.
We have another team, called implementation, that continuously delivers. Their work is less prone to bugs, so they skip going through the Test environment completely. Their work needs to be released to the Acceptance environment as soon as possible to show customers their upcoming changes, and they want to release to Production environment every a week.
what I want
We want to implement a gitflow based way of working to accomplish the above. So the Acceptance environment gets releases once every 2 weeks from the developer team, but continuously gets releases from the implementation team. And the production environment gets releases every week, one week from both development and implementation, and the other week only from implementation.
The challenge is that when the implementation team wants to release changes to the Acceptance or Production environment, I don't want to release any untested or unaccepted changes from the develop team.
my proposal
Now I have thought up a branching strategy based upon gitflow, but with a second long lived branch next to develop named impl (see image below). Once a week I create a release branch, one week based from the develop branch (yellow arrows in image) and the other week based from the impl branch (blue arrow in image). Once changes are released to Production environment, they end up on the master branch and get backmerged to both the develop and impl branch.
my question
But I'm afraid I'm doing something dangerous here. My question is, will this branching strategy work, or will it sometimes lose earlier changes because the release branches get pull requests from different 'parents'?
For example, the changes that the develop team has done in the first two weeks, will end up in the develop branch at the beginning of the third week. At that moment, those changes aren't yet available in the impl, or production branch.
The develop changes now go to a new release branch (from '2' to '10' in image). So now when the impl team pushed another change to the release branch (from '16 to '12' in image), should I fear that the develop changes will go lost? Because the release branch first got changes from the develop branch, and later got changes from the impl branch that doesn't yet have the develop changes?

PS. The black boxes with 'T', 'A' and 'P' indicate pipelines releasing to the Test, Acceptance and Production environments.

"The teams work in the same solution, but don't change the same files." Why don't they have separate modules and separate repositories then?

@freakish, they could be working with a monorepo (or some semblance thereof).

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@freakish Without going into too much detail, I can tell you that this thought has crosses our minds, but was seen as unfeasible, because of the messy state the parts are in.

@Community I believe to have a very clear question: Is the branching strategy in the picture going to work, or will changes start disappearing sometimes.

@nl-x yeah, I think you are solving the wrong problem then.

"Their work is less prone to bugs, so they skip going through the Test environment completely.".....

@Ewan I don't like it either. But both teams test every individual change when it's still in the feature branch, on the Developer environment. Just the implementation team refuses to do a full end-to-end test after their changes are reintegrated, and it is about to be released.

I don't think it works. If the developers release fails test at the end of week 1, you have a release branch that the implementation team want to go live, but the dev team wants not to go live.
While not breaking, I also think you set yourself up for merge issues at the start (half way through?) of each dev sprint where the dev team has the week of work they have just completed, plus the week of work the implementation team has completed to merge together before they can continue their sprint.
Also, is you diagram correct? at the end of week one you get half a dev sprint + implementation work, this doesn't seem to match your description.
I don't think it would work if you have to release half a sprints worth of dev work.
What I would suggest, assuming you cant split the application into code and content or something similar, is

Don't skip testing
1 Week sprints, less changes = faster testing
Pre-test features individually
Select features that you want to release each week and make a release out of them. Rather than merging "completed by not tested" features into dev/imp

The idea being to speed up testing by only having to test that features work together in your test env, and not to let the big/hard/dev features hold back small/easy/implementation features.

I think the diagram is correct, though, I should have made every arrow that goes from blue to green, into a blue arrow. Because impl is continuously deploying to the Acceptance environment. The work of develop only goes to Acceptance after the end of every sprint with the yellow arrows.

The rest of what you say is true. But needs more change from the teams, rather than a fix I can offer from automation side. This is a political process that is in motion, but I cannot force. Yes, either develop will need to adapt to the same pace of releases as impl, or impl will need to change the other way around.

Simpler is better here. Reorient the release cadence for this application to the more frequent releases. This establishes your heartbeat.
The implementation team should be merging work into master. Once they have done their testing, create a release branch off master. Don't merge anything into master unless it can be released later that week. Presumably, the implementation team is handling more urgent issues. Optimize your version control strategy to accommodate their schedule so version control does not get in their way.
How you handle the development team's work depends on how much automated testing you have. If you have enough automated test coverage (unit tests, integration tests, end-to-end tests, etc) then I recommend trunk-based development. The development team merges their work in progress into master and hides it behind feature toggles. With sufficient automated test coverage, you release once per week, but the new enhancements are hidden from end users.
With insufficient automated test coverage, though, trunk-based development is not a good option. The in-progress work from the developer team is an unmitigated risk for the implementation team. You don't want the implementation team fighting fires every other week.
The key here is isolating the developer team's work. I would create a "development" branch off of master. The developer team merges work into the development branch and performs the necessary testing so they can merge it into master at the beginning of the 1-week implementation release cycle.
Hotfixes can be merged into a release branch. Keep that flow simple. Presumably hotfixes are more akin to emergencies. No sense in mixing it with implementation or development work. Just be sure to merge the release branch into master.
Periodically, at the discretion of the developer team, you will need to merge master into development. Maybe at the beginning of the developer team's 2-week cycle. Ideally, more often than that. Once a day would be better so merge conflicts are easier to resolve. Then again, if the two teams are working on different files, merge conflicts aren't going to be an issue. Application behavior might be the bigger concern, which can be mitigated with proper QA and regression testing.

Thanks for your extensive answer. However, I would love to also hear if the proposed solution by me (the picture) will also work, or not. All things you said have already crossed our discussions and are valid. But currently, the codebase is not ready for trunk based development (insufficient automated testing, longer living feature branches, etc). Having implementation branch off and merge back in to master is something we're looking at, but that would lead implementation more towards continuous delivery.

@nl-x, it sounds like implementation is already doing continuous delivery. The branching strategy in the question is quite complex. Every merge is an opportunity to introduce defects, which puts your weekly releases at risk.
